# Rspec controller test expects object gots ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to create a basic test for my controller using the example here: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

```
describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns @orders" do
      order = Order.create(id:1)
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:orders)).to eq([order])
    end
  end
```

Result is :

Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:orders)).to eq([order])

```
   expected: [#<Order id: 1, quantity: nil, company_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
        got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

I don't understand why I get `ActiveRecord::Relation []` instead of the order object

Comment: why use `eq([order])` instead of `eq(order)`?

Comment: Are you setting `@orders` variable in the controller?

Comment: @Sandra results are same for both of them

Comment: @bsvin33t yes i am setting.

Comment: "I don't understand why I get ActiveRecord::Relation [] instead of the order object" - well, the answer is in your controller. You probably have something like `@orders = Order.all` there. That's a lazy query. It does not execute until you try to read from it, which you do not here. The easiest way to get past this error is to make the query eager: `Order.all.to_a`. This _will_ give you an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`match_array`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-8/docs/matchers/activerecord-relation-match-array) instead:

```
it "assigns @orders" do
  order = Order.create(id:1)
  get :index
  expect(assigns(:orders)).to match_array([order])
end
```

Comment: I have recollection of writing such code, but I haven't tested it. The examples on the relish have similar syntax - create an array and match it with a relation.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think I ever tried it against a relation, but I have no reason not to trust the docs.